# Formatting Web Ontology RDF File in Centos OS

Tags: unix, rdf, owl

I am trying to reformat RDF file for [LOINC](https://loinc.org/document-ontology/). The file looks something like following

```
   <!-- 
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //
        // Classes
        //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         -->
    .
    .
    .   
    
    
      <!-- https://loinc.org/LP189614-3 -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="https://loinc.org/LP189614-3">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://loinc.org/LP173103-5"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Weight management summary (LP)</rdfs:label>
        <skos:prefLabel rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Weight management summary</skos:prefLabel>
        <loinc:hasCode rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">LP189614-3</loinc:hasCode>
    </owl:Class>
    
  .
  .
  .
  .

<!-- https://loinc.org/LP173103-5 -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="https://loinc.org/LP173103-5">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://loinc.org/LP173122-5"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Summary (LP)</rdfs:label>
        <skos:prefLabel rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Summary</skos:prefLabel>
        <loinc:hasCode rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">LP173103-5</loinc:hasCode>
    </owl:Class>
    
.
.

.
    <!-- https://loinc.org/LP192135-4 -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="https://loinc.org/LP192135-4">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://loinc.org/LP172961-7"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Birth defects (LP)</rdfs:label>
        <skos:prefLabel rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Birth defects</skos:prefLabel>
        <loinc:hasCode rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">LP192135-4</loinc:hasCode>
    </owl:Class>   
    .
    .
    .
```

The whole file is 5 MB and available [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zatppNEhglqR0LX4HFCWK4Ez3V8_tFBm/view?usp=sharing). The output of the file should be JSON and for every owl class, output should look like the following.

```
{
  "id": "https://loinc.org/LP189614-3",#The subject URI without enclosing <> 
  "Label":"Weight management summary", #The text label of a Concept: <skos:prefLabel rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Weight management summary</skos:prefLabel>**
  "Definition": "", #The text definition of a Concept. Empty since there is no definition
  "Alt_Definition":"", #Alternate Definition(s) of a Concept. Empty since there is no alt_definition
  "Synonyms":"Weight management summary", #Synonym(s) for a Concept: <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Weight management summary (LP)</rdfs:label>
  "Parent":"Summary", #Superclass(es): Get Parents <skos:prefLabel rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Summary</skos:prefLabel>**
  "Child":"", #Subclass(es): PrefLabels of all subClasses
  "ICD_and_skosNotation":"", #ICD9 or ICD10 codes. Empty since there is none
  "Genes":"", #Associated Genes
  "Source_Ontology":"LOINC", #Ontology a Concept is derived from: Always LOINC
  "Data_Element_Mapping":0, #Flag indicating if the Concept has a Mapped Data Element
  "Data_Element":0, #Flag indicating if the Concept is a Data Element
  "General":"", #Field to accommodate any data not captured elsewhere in the schema
}
```

I have basic Sed and Awk knowledge but it seems to be more complicated than that because for every owl class, all of its parents and children are needed. Are there any tools or scripts that can make this formatting easier?

Per suggestion, I have used the following to convert RDF to JSON. However, I am not sure how to get parent and children information populated.

```
from rdflib import plugin, Graph
from rdflib.serializer import Serializer

g=Graph()
g.parse(location='LOINC.rdf',format='application/rdf+xml')
g.serialize(destination='output_json-ld.txt',format='json-ld',indent=4)
```

Comment: I recommend using Python and the BeautifulSoup module to parse and re-form the information.

Comment: @JamesMcPherson Please help improve the quality of question. I am not an expert coder but I am willing to put in effort once I know the right direction

Comment: Instead of -ve repping this post, help improve or make suggestions!

Comment: You've got XML, and `sed` + `awk` aren't your friends here. What need is an XML parser (I suggest BeautifulSoup) - have a read through https://pythonprogramming.net/tables-xml-scraping-parsing-beautiful-soup-tutorial/. With your source doc, you can walk through the `<owl:...>` and pull out each element and its relationship into a `dict()`, then use `json.dump()` on the dict to print it.

Comment: There is no need to use an XML tool or sed/awk first here. There are plenty of RDF tools that allow for at least convert to 1) a line based format called N-Triples or even to JSON-LD. Please have a look at JSON-LD format. Tools are for example rapper, Apache Jena, RDF4J, ...

Comment: @UninformedUser Please see updated post with Python code